# Access to different tabs in a tabpanel using # in URL - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I've created a simple tabpanel, with 3 tabs. 
The first tab is displayed when the page is created.

Assume the URL is /welcome

I'm wondering if it possible to bind each tab to a # ?
If you click on the first tab, the url becomes /welcome#1, /welcome#2 if you click on the 2th, etc.
I think this is possible as I already did this with region that could be updated/destroyed, but the main problem is if you type /welcome#3 in the URL and then load the page, the first tab will be shown, and not the third.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the init function of your app.js, you can recover your url thanks to

```
document.location.href
```

Extract (thanks to a split) your selected tab and add it to a static var.

In the launch function of your app.js, get the tabPanel object thanks to a

```
   var tabPanel =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemIdOfYourTabPanel')[0]
```

and set the select tab like this :

```
tabPanel.setActiveTab(tab);
```